# react router not rendering components on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On initial load of the application it will render the correct component corresponding to the URL However, but when I change click on link, it render nothing.

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store/store';
import { App } from './components/app/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';



render(

    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Mye file app.tsx where I put my routers:
This is what I'm intending the routes components to look like.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { history } from '../../utils/helpers';
import { alertActions } from '../../store/actions'
import { PrivateRoute } from '../../routes';
import { Home, Login } from './components/';

interface AProps {
    alert: {
        message: string,
        type: string
    },
    clearAlerts: () => { type: string }
}

class App extends React.Component<AProps> {
    constructor(props: AProps) {
        super(props);

        history.listen((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            // clear alert on location change
            this.props.clearAlerts();
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            {alert.message &&
                                <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>{alert.message}</div>
                            }
                            <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                                {/* <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} /> */}
                                {/* <Redirect from="*" to="/" /> */}
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

function mapState(state: any) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return { alert };
}

const actionCreators = {
    clearAlerts: alertActions.clear
};

const connectedApp = withRouter(connect(mapState, actionCreators)(App));
export { connectedApp as App };
```

s there something I'm missing to get components to render clicking Link? I'm not getting any console errors or anything telling me there's an issue. So not sure if components are not wrapped correctly or what may be causing the issue.

Comment: One strange thing I see in your snippet is that you have 2 Routers? One inside `index` file, another inside `app` file. That is might be the case. Could you try to remove one of them?

Comment: Thank you Danila, I removed router from app.tsx and its worked fine. Thank you so much again, but I want use Router inside app.tsx and remove router at index.tsx, because I want to use history, but when I do that its not working.

Comment: You are using different routers `BrowserRouter` and regular `Router`, did you tried both of them? You also still can use history the same way in your `index` file like you did in `app`

Comment: I tried using this 

    <Provider store={store}><Router history={history}><App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,document.getElementById('app'));   its not working

Comment: Did you try `<BrowserRouter history={history}>` inside `index`?

Comment: Its working, I did  <Router history={history}>
                <App />
            </Router>

Comment: Cool! I'll duplicate my answer so you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 2 Routers at the same time. One inside `index` file, another inside `app` file. You might want to remove one of them.

For example, only leave one inside `index`:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <App />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

to this:

```
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Comment: This should not affect anything since Link has just `/login` path anyway, without any nesting, additional params or whatsoever.